# Apache configuration "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I have a zend project. It was working before, nothing changed in the source. When it was working it was on manually instaled apache 2.2 , php 5.3 . After that I installed xampp but apache was showing error on every post i made (sometimes it makes double post). I decided to install apache 2.2 and php 5.4 but now its showing me "The page isn't redirecting properly". 
My apache configuration (lines that I changed): 
httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/Apache2.2/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
PHPIniDir "c:/Apache2.2/PHP"

# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<Directory "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

httpd-vhosts:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@rma.com        
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\rma\public"
    ServerName rma.com
    ErrorLog "logs/rma-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/rma-access.log" common
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\rma\public>
 Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

php.ini

```
[APC]
extension=php_apc.dll
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 64M
apc.max_file_size = 10M
apc.stat=1

extension_dir = "C:\Apache2.2\PHP\ext"
```

What I am doing wrong? There is nothing changed in the source and its kind of working in xampp and wamp ? Thanks !

Comment: I am still stuck at this.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that php 5.4 have some problems with apc. Now i am using xcache. Hope this helps someone.